# Where is the physical path or way to go to heaven?

Tags: heaven

Many people have gone to heaven while still being alive like -Arjun . I want to know what is the physical path or way to to go heaven ?

Also I have heard that there is staircase to heaven located at mount Kailash.

Also In Mahabharat Swargarohan Parva , it is clear that Pandavs and Draupdi were climbing some mountain to go to heaven physically. (Although only Yudhistira succeeded ) . Which mountain it was ?

Comment: Do you mean the physical path? Or the deeds that one must do in order to reach heaven?

Comment: @CDR Physical path to heaven.

Answer (score 1):

The Pandavas and Draupadi's ascension takes place in the previous Parva, Mahaprasthanika, where they climb various mountains, including Himavant and Meru:

> **17.2.1. Then, they, with their minds fixed on the north, saw a great mountain with a snow-covered sky (Himavant).**
>
> **17.2.2 Then they crossed it and saw a sea of sand and beheld the great mountain Meru, the best of peaks.**

Himavant ("snow-covered") is understood as referring to the Himalayas or Kailasa.

In the next chapter, it is explained that the other Pandavas and Draupadi attained heaven and are waiting for Yudhishthira there:

> **17.3.5. You will see your brothers, who have gone to heaven before you, all with Krishna. Do not grieve, O best of the Bharatas.**